# Sony stamina mode on Android phones

Tags: android, sony

I've got an app that causes a warning message on some sony phones that's something like

"app name" is preventing STAMINA mode from saving power in standby. If you use this application often, ignore this warning. If not, uninstall or force stop the application."

I was wondering what criteria sony is using to put up this message as it might give me a chance of getting my app to run with stamina mode on if I knew what checks were being done.

Comment: Im facing the same thing, did you find anything for it ?